# Getting a value from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a bit confused with the array that I have to work with. The following array:

```
print_r($myArray);
```

returns the following:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 88
        [label] => Bus
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 89
        [label] => Bike
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 90
        [label] => Plane
    )
    [3] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 91
        [label] => Submaine
    )
    [4] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 92
        [label] => Boat
    )
    [5] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 93
        [label] => Car
    )
    [6] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 94
        [label] => Truck
    )
)
```

How do I get the label value, say, "**Submaine**", if I have the **$id = 91**?

Comment: If you can change the way the array is constructed, you should index the items with the "id", that will be easier. Then you can just do `$item = $myArray[$id];`

Comment: A class is creating this array, so unfortunately I have to work with what I've got. But you're right, I wish I could just call by ID.

Answer (score 7):

This will get you the object(s) you seek:

`$objects = array_filter($myArray, function($item){ return $item->id == 91 })`

Then it's just a matter of getting the attribute of the object that you want.

Comment: Those are objects, so it would be `return $item->id == 91`

Comment: +1 For suggesting array_filter rather than the obvious array looping.

Comment: onteria_ is correct, but AJ's answer is the best from three available now (the part mentioned by onteria_ is the only issue here).

Comment: It's a lovely solution, just far slower.

Comment: slower if the search value is anywhere but the end of the array, otherwise they're both O(n).

Comment: @AJ Well, yes, but that isn't exactly unlikely, is it? If we're assuming that the last item is the one we want, the fastest solution is `array_pop`! (I'm being facetious, but still...)

Comment: absolutely. not saying i disagree with you.  what would be interesting is if `array_filter` was updated to support an optional `max_items` parameter so that it stops searching once `n` matches is found.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to loop through the array, I think.

```
$value = '';
foreach ($myArray as $el) {
    if ($el->id === 91) { // or other number
        $value = $el->label;
        break;
    }
}
```

The label is now contained in `$value`.

---

Benchmark values vs AJ's version for 1000000 iterations ([see source](http://pastebin.com/9MCd8ZQf)):

```
lonesomeday: 1.8717081546783s
AJ: 4.0924150943756s
James C: 2.9421799182892s
```

Comment: +1 for posting a benchmark, this is very interesting ! What did you use for benchmarking ?

Comment: @Matthieu A quick script I wrote myself -- see the link in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is an array of objects. I'd suggest re-keying the array by id like this:

```
$new = array();
foreach($array as $obj) {
    $new[ $obj->id ] = $new[ $obj->label ];
}
```

Now you've got a nice associative array that you can use normally e.g. `echo $new[92]` will echo "Boat"